# Why can't you get the return type of a function call directly through typeof in typescript

Tags: typescript

I wrote the following typescript code, hoping to get the inferred return value of function fn:

```js
declare const fn: <T>(arg: T) => T extends string ? number : boolean;

type a1 = typeof fn("abc");
```

But typeof cannot be applied directly to function calls。

I found a similar question, but I looked at the relevant answers and did not answer my doubts. Please let me explain my intention to clear it.

I understand that the return value can be obtained in the following way

```js
type a2 = ReturnType<typeof fn>
```

But this loses type inference, and I expect to be able to infer the true type by calling the function directly, so I can do this in the following way：

```js
const ret = fn("abc");

type a3 = typeof ret;
```

This approach fits my core needs, but 'ret' seems redundant, my ideal way of writing it is the first snippet I post, but typescript doesn't seem to support it, which strikes me as odd. typeof can be used to extract the typeof a value. It should make sense to place a method call to its right to retrieve the type of the function's return value.

Some friends couldn't understand why I refused to pass generic arguments directly to generic functions. I tried to express my thoughts: When I was writing typescript, I wanted users to use all the generic functions as normal functions without passing generic parameters. The functions would infer all types based on the actual parameters passed in by users, and the generic parameters I placed were only used to infer related types, not let users pass in. Because I think the user explicitly passing in generic parameters looks very unintelligent, generics are meant to help with type inference, not something the user should pass in directly.

I reorganized my question, and I think my biggest question was why `type a1 = typeof fn("ABC");` doesn't work, it looks very intuitive, and I wish there was some other concise way to write it, but it doesn't look like there is. '”

Comment: "I cannot pass generic arguments" please make a proper example of a function. For the above `fn` you can, and that means "do pass generic arguments, you can't cannot pass generic arguments (like `ReturnType<typeof fn< typeof "abc" >>`)" will be an answer unless you provide a proper example

Comment: What is your primary question? Is it the post title? If so, the answer is that it was originally considered [too complex](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606#issuecomment-372810978) to implement, and there is an open issue at [ms/TS#40179](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179) requesting it, so it's a missing feature.  (more)

Comment: (continued) Instantiation expressions are the closest you can get right now but you have said that doesn't meet your requirements.  If your question is "how can I simply this" then I think the answer is "you can't", given your constraints. Please [edit] to clarify the actual question, and then let me know which, if either of these I should flesh out into an answer.

Comment: I recalibrated the question and my thoughts, and I did my best to express my thoughts on why I couldn't pass in generic parameters directly

Comment: Aside: `Because I think the user explicitly passing in generic parameters looks very unintelligent, generics are meant to help with type inference, not something the user should pass in directly.` It depends on what the use case is. Narrowing the input type, linking the return type to the input type, e.g.; are fine. But there definitely are cases where you would pass the generic to the function; either to enforce a type or because the type cannot be inferred (in which case the alternative is asserting the return type, or similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer for "why isn't `typeof fn("abc")` supported?" is that nobody has implemented support for it.  It takes effort to support features, and [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) does not, by default, apply to arbitrary TypeScript expressions.

Support for `typeof fn("abc")` was proposed, along with `typeof expr` for any TypeScript expression `expr`, in [microsoft/TypeScript#6606](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606), but it was eventually [closed as "Too Complex"](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6606#issuecomment-372810978) with the rationale that [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) such as [the `ReturnType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) would serve most purposes for so-called "call types".  Of course `ReturnType<T>` only works for non-[generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), non-[overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) functions.

Note that [instantiation expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#instantiation-expressions) make it at least possible to express what happens when you instantiate a generic function's type parameter(s).  So if you have a function `declare function func<T, U, V>(⋯): ⋯`, then you can write `typeof func<X, Y, Z>` to get the type of the function you'd get if you called `func<X, Y, Z>(⋯);`  So if you were calling `fn("abc")`, then the type parameter `T` would be instantiated with the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"abc"`, and so the return type can be represented as `ReturnType<typeof fn<"abc">>`.  But this does not directly let you plug in the function's value arguments, and get the compiler to *infer* the type arguments.  So it doesn't meet your requirements as stated in the question.

There is currently an open feature request for call types at [microsoft/TypeScript#40179](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179).  If this were implemented you would have the ability to write `typeof fn("abc")` or something like it.  It is currently marked as "Awaiting More Feedback", meaning they need to see more upvotes ( on the opening comment of the issue) and more comments describing why it would be important to implement and how current workarounds are insufficient.  If you really want to see this implemented, it wouldn't hurt to go there and give it such an upvote and a comment.  It probably wouldn't *help* much either, but it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I looked at the issues you provided and it seems that the proposal is a completely new feature, although there are some similarities but there are some differences compared to the question I raised, which in my opinion is a feature that should be supported, if I use the analogy, I think it is like a programming language declaration and initialization. If a programming language supports declaration and initialization separately, then the declaration and initialization written together should also be supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can.
Consider this example:

```js
declare const fn: <T>(arg: T) => T extends string ? number : boolean;

type a1 = ReturnType<typeof fn<'str'>>; // number
type a2 = ReturnType<typeof fn<22>>; // boolean
```

You were very close here `type a2 = ReturnType<typeof fn>` bu you did not specify generic argument

Comment: The passed generics do not meet my requirements, the actual type of the generics should come from the type inference of the actual passed function parameters, I have already added to the problem

Comment: @Autumn I dont think it is possible to simplify it more

Comment: Maybe as you say, the issue is a typescript issue, and typescript doesn't provide the simplicity I want

Comment: Try 'typeof  (fn(42))"

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this example:

```
type ReturnTypeOf<T> = T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ? R : never;
const fn = <T>(arg: T) => arg as T extends string ? number : boolean;
type a3 = ReturnTypeOf<typeof fn>;
```

Comment: The passed generics do not meet my requirements, the actual type of the generics should come from the type inference of the actual passed function parameters, I have already added to the problem